# Need help writing a function to make any box inside the grid clickable and filled with colorwheel

Tags: javascript, html, function, canvas

I'm working on a pixel art project. What I was expecting to do here is be able to click any box inside the grid and render it with the the color from a color input.

I managed to understand how the loop works to create a grid using canvas and javascript. Next, I created a function called `colorPicker()` which allows me to click on any of the grid cells and take the value from the color input and render it that color. I used `canvas.addEventListener("click", function(event) { ... })`
and passed variables `xCoord` and `yCoord` with the value of `event.x` and `event.y`. This allows me to return the position of the mouse on click inside the grid.

The problem I'm running into right now is that it is only rendering 1 square out of all 400 I have drawn on the grid. The rendering works, it's just I can only click one box and render its color from the input.

Can anyone provide me with some help to solve this function just using the javascript logic I currently have right now?

```js
var title = document.getElementById("title");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var color = document.getElementById("color");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// The function that draws the grid     
function drawGrid() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#009EFF";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;

  // The for loop that draws the x-axis
  for (x = 0; x <= 400; x += 20) {
    ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(x, 400);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  // The for loop that draws the y-axis
  for (y = 0; y <= 400; y += 20) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, y);
    ctx.lineTo(400, y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

drawGrid();

// Function that clicks and fill grid boxes w / color
function colorPicker() {
  canvas.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var newColor = color.value;
    ctx.fillStyle = newColor;
    xCoord = event.x;
    yCoord = event.y;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 20);

    console.log(xCoord, yCoord);
    console.log(newColor);
  });
}

colorPicker();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-size: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-wheel">
  Color: <input type="color" id="color" />
</div>

<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this line:

```js
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
```

Instead of filling the clicked cell, you’re filling only the upper left cell on every click.

Currently you’re just using (0, 0) here, when you should be calculating this position from the cursor. The coordinates used by the canvas and the cursor are different though, so you’ll need to write a conversion function:

```js
function mousePosToCanvasPos(mouseX, mouseY) {
  var canvasPos = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    x: Math.floor((mouseX - canvasPos.x) / 20) * 20,
    y: Math.floor((mouseY - canvasPos.y) / 20) * 20,
  };
}
```

The `mousePosToCanvasPos()` function gets the current rendered position of the canvas (`canvasPos`), and calculates the offset of the cursor from the upper left corner of the canvas (`mouse_ - canvasPos._`). It then rounds this value down to the nearest multiple of 20 to return the upper left corner of the clicked cell (`Math.floor((mouse_ - canvasPos._) / 20) * 20`). If you change your cell size to something other than 20, be sure to change it in this function too. Or better yet, extract the constant (`var cellSize = 20`).

Adding this function to your code gives us:

```js
var title = document.getElementById("title");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var color = document.getElementById("color");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// The function that draws the grid     
function drawGrid() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#009EFF";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;

  // The for loop that draws the x-axis
  for (x = 0; x <= 400; x += 20) {
    ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(x, 400);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  // The for loop that draws the y-axis
  for (y = 0; y <= 400; y += 20) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, y);
    ctx.lineTo(400, y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

drawGrid();

function mousePosToCanvasPos(mouseX, mouseY) {
  var canvasPos = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    x: Math.floor((mouseX - canvasPos.x) / 20) * 20,
    y: Math.floor((mouseY - canvasPos.y) / 20) * 20,
  };
}

// Function that clicks and fill grid boxes w / color
function colorPicker() {
  canvas.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var newColor = color.value;
    ctx.fillStyle = newColor;

    var canvasCellPos = mousePosToCanvasPos(event.x, event.y);
    ctx.fillRect(canvasCellPos.x, canvasCellPos.y, 20, 20);

    console.log(event.x, event.y);
    console.log(newColor);
  });
}

colorPicker();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-size: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-wheel">
  Color: <input type="color" id="color" />
</div>

<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

You’ll notice that something’s still not quite right here: every time you fill a cell, it makes its border thinner. To solve this, you need to remove one pixel from each side of your `fillRect`:

```js
ctx.fillRect(canvasCellPos.x + 1, canvasCellPos.y + 1, 18, 18);
```

```js
var title = document.getElementById("title");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var color = document.getElementById("color");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// The function that draws the grid     
function drawGrid() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#009EFF";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;

  // The for loop that draws the x-axis
  for (x = 0; x <= 400; x += 20) {
    ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(x, 400);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  // The for loop that draws the y-axis
  for (y = 0; y <= 400; y += 20) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, y);
    ctx.lineTo(400, y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

drawGrid();

function mousePosToCanvasPos(mouseX, mouseY) {
  var canvasPos = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    x: Math.floor((mouseX - canvasPos.x) / 20) * 20,
    y: Math.floor((mouseY - canvasPos.y) / 20) * 20,
  };
}

// Function that clicks and fill grid boxes w / color
function colorPicker() {
  canvas.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var newColor = color.value;
    ctx.fillStyle = newColor;

    var canvasCellPos = mousePosToCanvasPos(event.x, event.y);
    ctx.fillRect(canvasCellPos.x + 1, canvasCellPos.y + 1, 18, 18);

    console.log(event.x, event.y);
    console.log(newColor);
  });
}

colorPicker();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-size: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-wheel">
  Color: <input type="color" id="color" />
</div>

<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Every time you use `ctx.fillRect (...` you draw a new rectangle, so after 1000 clicks, you will have created 1000 rectangles, most of which are stacked on the previous ones drawn in the same place, right?

Comment: @MrJ `fillRect()` doesn’t create a “rectangle object”, it just sets the pixels within the specified rectangle to the specified color. Imagine using the fill tool on a rectangular selection in MS Paint.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I did not know. But how will he do to know, what is drawn, to save a trace?

Comment: @MrJ You can use [`canvas.toDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) to retrieve the image data from a canvas.

Comment: ok, but it's just a `data: image / png; base64` I was expecting something more useful, like vectors, to be able to transform them into JSON data, such as: [{x: A, y: Z, color: '# 26CB2E'}, {x:. ...]

Comment: @MrJ A canvas is just a bitmap image - there’s no vector data to be extracted. In this example, you could scan through and look at the color in a single pixel which you know is in each cell, then use that to generate a data structure of cell colors

Comment: @MrJ the code you provided me worked. It was the piece of code i was missing. As for resetting the board all i did was just create an input button which took an Id of btn and with dom i was able to create  function reset() which inside the block took another function btn.addEventListener("click" function){} and inside that i just called back to drawGrid() and the board would return to its original state. Basically draw over the original one. Not sure if that was right or not but it worked for me to reset the board. Thanks again MrJ!!

Comment: @MTCoster fillRect() does just fill the rectangle from its (x,y,w,h). awesome stuff!!